# Passing array of functions to another function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass arbitrary number of arguments to function. The arguments should be json type [function : arrayOfArgs]. The keys are functions and the values are arrays of the arguments, that should  be passed to those functions.

At first, I considered function with only a number of argument

```
 function _gl(f,args){ f.apply(null,args); }

 function func(a,b){ alert(a+b); }
```

//calling the  function

```
<input type="button" value="test" onclick="_gl(func,['2','3']);"/>
```

and it works pretty good .Now I'm trying to generalize that method

```
function _GL(){
      var arguments = _GL.arguments; 

      var i=0;
      for(i;i<arguments.length;i++)
      {
        var A=arguments[i];
        for(j in A) j.apply(null,A[j]); 
      } 
   }
```

//and calling it

```
<input type="button" value="TEST" onclick="_GL({func:['2','3']});"/>
```

but i'm getting the following error "Uncaught TypeError: Object func has no method 'apply' ".

Comment: `func` you pass is the Event object, it's not a function, and why should it?

Comment: You're passing the array `['2', '3']` to the attribute func.

Comment: `should be json type`...  JSON is a *string representation* of data.  Your array is *not* "JSON type".  It's just a "normal" JavaScript array.  If it was JSON, it's be a string.  If it's not a string, it's not JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bVNMF/):

```
_GL = function() {
    var arguments = _GL.arguments;
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var arg = arguments[i];
        for (j in arg) {
            var f = window[j];
            f.apply(null, arg[j]);
        }
    }
};
```

As you can see you have to get your function `f` first from the `window` element by its name. Then `f` has the right type an `args` can be applied.

Answer (score 1):

```
{func:['2','3']}
```

You are making an object with a (string) key called `"func"` with value `['2','3']`.  Strings are not functions, so it doesn't have `.apply()`.

In objects, your keys *must* be strings, you cannot use other types as keys.

---

To "generalize" it, you should pass it an array of functions and their arguments.  Something like this:

```
[[func, ['2','3']], [func2, ['abc']]
```

So, if you did this:

```
onclick="_GL([[func, ['2','3']], [func2, ['abc']]);"
```

Then you could loop through and get the functions and call 'em.

```
function _GL(funcs){
    for(var i=0, len=funcs.length; i < len; i++){
        var func = funcs[i];
        func[0].apply(null, func[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you RockeT Hazmat for your answer. What can I do to make that function work?

Comment: @Paramore: I edited my answer and gave you a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution;

```
var _gl = function (callables) {

    // Loop through each property in the passed in object
    for (var fnName in callables) {

        // Only apply for properties that is local to `callables`
        if (callables.hasOwnProperty(fnName)) {
            window[fnName].apply(callables[property]);
        }

    }

};

... onclick='_gl({"MyFunction": ["a", 1, []]});' ...
```

Instead of using the global namespace, you could (and should!) set up an object with your callable functions.